# "Uninitialized constant" error when using RSpec in a Rails 3.1 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spork

I'm trying to use RSpec to test a Rails 3.1rc4 project. I want to test the code I have in my `lib/` directory. I'm getting:

```
/home/julas/myapp/spec/lib/operation_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MyApp (NameError)
```

MyApp is a module (namespace) and the problem appears whenever I try to use something from this namespace, e.g. when I try to do

```
describe MyApp::Something do
```

in my test.

The test worked without any problems earlier. I load all the stuff form the `lib/` to the Rails environment by adding `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` to `application.rb`.

I'm really clueless what causes this. Anyone experienced something similar?

**Update:** it seems it wasn't related with Spork. I must have missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why this worked earlier, but it seems that to test the code from the `lib` directory you have to require it in the spec file (it is not auto-loaded like in e.g. controllers). [Source](http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/a565ce19c2be0e02)

Answer (score 1):

I was already loading the code from `lib/`. My issue was, my test had:

```
require "spec_helper"
```

instead of

```
require 'rails_helper'
```